# Ixalan's Binding and Ashiok, Nightmare Muse

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I cast [Ixalan's Binding](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIxalan%27s%5d%2b%5bBinding%5d), and its etb targets and exiles my opponent's [Rampaging Baloths](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRampaging%20Baloths%5d). Later in the game I use the -7 on [Ashiok, Nightmare Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAshiok%2c%20Nightmare%20Muse%5d), choosing to cast my opponent's exiled Rampaging Baloths.

**Can my opponent now cast another copy of Rampaging Baloths, since the previously exiled copy is no longer under Binding, or can they still not cast cards named Rampaging Baloths?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a ruling on Gatherer:

> If there is no exiled card (perhaps because the exiled permanent was a
>   token or was a commander that moved to the command zone in the
>   Commander variant), Ixalan’s Binding won’t stop players from casting
>   spells.

If you cast the card from exile using Ashiok then there is no more exiled card.  Therefore, your opponent can cast whatever they want, including Rampaging Baloths.

Comment: This ruling could still leave some players unsure; as it refers to what happens in situations when there never was any exiled card. In the OP's case, there actually was an exiled card, it just stopped being exiled.

Comment: An example being in the case of tricks like with Fiend Hunter, sacrificing it and causing it's leave-the-battlefield to trigger with no cards in exile.

Answer (score 6):

They will now be able to cast Rampaging Baloths again.

Ixalan's Binding has linked abilities on it; and in order for the second ability to do anything, the card exiled by the first ability must still be in exile.

> 607. Linked Abilities
>
>      > 607.2a If an object has an activated or triggered ability printed on it that instructs a player to exile one or more cards and an ability printed on it that refers either to “the exiled cards” or to cards “exiled with [this object],” these abilities are linked. **The second ability refers only to cards in the exile zone** that were put there as a result of an instruction to exile them in the first ability.